# There is no hot water at kitchen sink. It flows, but not hot. There is hot water everywhere else in the house.

Tags: plumbing

There is hot water everywhere in the house except the kitchen. The water flows but is not hot. When I turn off the hot water shut off under the sink some cold water still flows but it never gets hot. Could this be only due to a bad shut off valve?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. What changed when you closed that sink's hot water shutoff? What if you open the hot water shutoff and close the cold water shutoff?

Comment: When I closed the hot water shut off, some cold water kept flowing. Nothing changed when I closed the cold water shut off.

Comment: Is this a new situation; if so, then what changed? (It sounds like your pipes are crossed, but that isn't something that happens spontaneously.)